# Centering HTML5 Responsive Canvas Text

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, center

I'm using the following function to allow app users to insert text onto their canvas photo. It works as expected with the text shrinking as it nears the edge but I cannot figure out how to center the text if it is not larger than the canvas.

```
var canvas4 = document.getElementById("canvas4");
        var ctx4 = canvas4.getContext("2d");

        canvas4.width = $(window).width();
        canvas4.height = $(window).height();

        var txt = value,
            tw,
            oc, octx;
        ctx4.font = '40px sans-serif';
        ctx4.fillStyle = 'blue';
        ctx4.textBaseline = 'top';
        ctx4.globalAlpha = 0.50;

        tw = ctx4.measureText(txt).width;

        if (tw > canvas4.width - 20) {
                oc = document.createElement('canvas');
                octx = oc.getContext('2d');
                oc.width = tw;
                oc.height = parseInt(ctx4.font, 10) * 1.2;
                octx.font = '40px sans-serif';
                octx.textBaseline = 'top';
                octx.fillText(txt, 0, 0);
                ctx4.drawImage(oc, 10, canvas4.height - 100, canvas4.width - 20, (canvas4.width - 20) / tw * oc.height);
        } else {
            ctx4.fillText(txt, 10, canvas4.height - 100);
        };
```

I have attempted text align such as
`ctx4.textAlign = 'center, canvas4.width / 2, canvas4.height - 100';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`textAlign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/textAlign) just takes one word, `"center"`. The rest goes in your `fillText` call.

```
ctx4.textAlign = 'center';
ctx4.fillText(txt, canvas4.width / 2, canvas4.height - 100);
```

Setting `textAlign` to `"center"` makes the center of the text appear at the point specified in the `fillText` call. If that point is centered on the canvas, the entire text will be centered on the canvas.

Comment: setting textAlign to center makes the text start to the left off the screen.

Comment: Thanks... thought I had tried that but I guess I messed something up because its working as you explained centering and this saves the extra calculation on the solution I came up with. Selecting this as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
ctx.fillText("Your text here",canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
```

I have no experience with canvas element. But this will help you.

Comment: I don't think setting the x and y to half the canvas size helps me... since I'm already setting those without the desired results. I *think* some math needs to be done with tw (the measureText) width in conjunction with the canvas width. I'm just not very mathematical to know what.

Comment: I figured it out... I feel a little dumb :D

The solution is to take half the canvas size then subtract half the text width.

ctx4.fillText(txt, canvas4.width/2 - tw/2, canvas4.height - 100);